# Can't Migrate Foreign Key

Tags: php, laravel-5, migrate

Here is Vehicles migrate :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('serie');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->integer('power');
            $table->float('capacity');
            $table->float('speed');
            $table->integer('maker_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('Vehicles', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('maker_id')->references('id')->on('Makers');
        });
    }
```

Here is Makers Migrate :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Makers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('phone');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

When I run artisan migrate , I got following error messages.

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `api`.`#sql-14b0_71
 ` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter t
 able `Vehicles` add constraint `vehicles_maker_id_foreign` foreign key (`ma
 ker_id`) references `Makers` (`id`))



 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `api`.`#sql-14b0_71
 ` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I want to create two tables: Vehicles & Makers . In vehicles , maker_id is foreign key . I read the some references for laravel migration from various sources. But I can't find solution.

Comment: Which migration runs first? If Vehicles is run first then there is no Makers table to add the reference to.

Comment: Plop your `$table->foreign('maker_id')->references('id')->on('Makers');` underneath `$table->integer('maker_id')->unsigned();` and remove the `Schema::table('Vehicles', function (Blueprint $table)` block. Try that. As jfadich notes, you need to have the referenced key in a table that already exists and so in a table in an earlier migration.

Comment: Now I run the makers migrate first, and then I run the vehicles migrate . But I got error too. @Jonathan I follow the steps you commented . But I got error still.

Comment: What error? If you have to, are you able to drop your database and run the migration again? Sometimes you can screw up the database when these migration errors occur. Something *like* `mysql -u homestead -p'secret' --execute="drop database homestead; create database homestead;"`. Bear in mind the obvious consequences of destroying the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to your migration files order, you have two solutions:

1. Change order: make `Makers Migrate` file first then `Vehicles Migrate`.
2. If `Makers Migrate` file comes  after `Vehicles Migrate` file and you don't want to change order, move this:

   ```
   Schema::table('Vehicles', function (Blueprint $table){
       $table->foreign('maker_id')->references('id')->on('Makers');
   });
   ```

   To `Makers Migrate` file.

Comment: You need to run `makers migrate` first !

Answer (score 0):

Now I delete makers migrate file and I run vehicles migrate file . Below is vehicles migrate file.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('serie');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->integer('power');
            $table->float('capacity');
            $table->float('speed');
            $table->integer('maker_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

But I got the below errors

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class CreateVehicleTable in C:\xampp\htdocs\m
yownapi\database\migrations\2016_07_05_190215_vehicles_table.php on line 35


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Cannot redeclare class CreateVehicleTable
```

Comment: You have the class `CreateVehicleTable` declared more than once

Answer (score 0):

Now it is work properly with below codes

Makers Migrate

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MakersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Makers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('phone');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('Vehicles', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('maker_id')->references('id')->on('makers');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('Makers');
    }
}
```

Vehicles Migrate

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class VehiclesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('serie');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->float('power');
            $table->float('capacity');
            $table->integer('maker_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('Vehicles');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this. From your **Vehicles** migration, make the following changes

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('Vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('serie');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->integer('power');
        $table->float('capacity');
        $table->float('speed');
        $table->integer('maker_id')
        $table->foreign('maker_id')
              ->references('id')->on('Makers');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And since you will be adding the values form the **id** column in **Makers**, Laravel already has got your back, so there is really no need to add the unsigned() property there. Its still Okay if you add it there.

Hope I have answered your question. [For More Details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)